# How to print from a csv file based on DOB

Tags: python, csv, addressbook, date

I am trying to create a program that will scan the csv file (example below) for a date of birth and use the month in the date of birth to print a row that contains the month of birth that the user has input.

So far this is how I have structured my code:

```
import csv
dob = int(input('Input dob: '))
month = dob.split('/')
with open('AddressBook.csv', newline='') as myfile:
    reader = csv.reader(myfile)
    for row in reader:
        if month[1] in row:
            print(row)
        else:
            ()
```

whenever I test it says:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '11/02/65'
```

I would like to know how to fix this.

[image: Example from csv. file]

Any help on how to get the program running would be appreciated.

Comment: I hope your picture doesn't reveal actual personal details of real people.

Comment: No it's not real people

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform `int()` on a string which isn't numeric. Take out the `int()`. If you need the value to be numeric, `int(month[1])` should work.

(Your code should cope if the user passes in a string which doesn't match your expected input. Maybe loop back if there aren't exactly two slashes with suitable numbers between them. Probably some users will try to write 1989-05-13 or 5/13 1989, especially since the program shows no indication of how to format the input date. )

Comment: Ok the "error" is gone! Thankyou for that, but for some reason when I enter the dob, although it accepts it as valid, it does not print anything. Can you explain why?

Comment: This is my current code (if it helps):

     import csv
    dob = input('Input dob (DD/MM/YYYY): ')
    month = dob.split('/')
    with open('AddressBook.csv', newline='') as myfile:
        reader = csv.reader(myfile)
        for row in reader:
            if int(month[1]) in row:
                print(row)
            else:
                ()